# Saving users data even if the bot go offline or it get an update

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Good evening,
I'm developing a Discord bot, but I've a logic problem. I added some customizable variables, but if the bot goes offline or it get an update, all the user added datas will be delated. Should I store it in a external file, or in a database, or even use webhooks. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend storing your player variables in JSON files. They are easy to read and write to and require little extra code.

Example of a player data json file that stores xp and role variables:

```
{
  "407362137430687745": {
    "xpp": 2001,
    "xppr": 999182,
    "currentRole": "rank 4"
  },
  "389981749448409100": {
    "xpp": 112,
    "xppr": 148,
    "currentRole": "rank 2"
  },
  "405809293204520980": {
    "xpp": 100,
    "xppr": 128,
    "currentRole": "rank 1"
  }
}
```

They can be automatically listed under discord user ids, which lets you save to the player's keys in the json by using `message.author.id` and the like.

Example of writing to the json file:

```
const fs = require('fs') //importing file save
var xpPath = 'file path to json here'
var xpRead = fs.readFileSync(xpPath);
var xpFile = JSON.parse(xpRead); //ready for use
var userId = message.author.id //user id here
if (!xpFile[userId]) { //this checks if data for the user has already been created
    xpFile[userId] = {xpp: 0, xppr: 0, currentRole: ""}; //if not, create it
    fs.writeFileSync(xpPath, JSON.stringify(xpFile, null, 2));
} else {
    //as an example, I will give the owner of the id 50 xp and the role "Awesome Role"
    var xppVar = Number(xpFile.xpp) + 50 //add 50 to their original xp
    var xpprVar = Number(xpFile.xppr)
    var roleToGive = "Awesome Role"
    xpFile[userId] = {xpp: xppVar, xppr: xpprVar, currentRole: roleToGive};
    fs.writeFileSync(xpPath, JSON.stringify(xpFile, null, 2));
    console.log(`Changed that player's xp to ${xppVar} and gave him the role ${roleToGive}`)

}
```

It would be very simple to implement this in your bot, because all you would have to do is change the keys in the json file and code to what you want and create a json file.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the type/amount of data you're wanting to save. But you'll probably want to setup a database if you're saving user data. Try checking out MongoDB or rethinkDb